# div can't be side by side

Tags: css, xhtml

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/kXesZ/. The 2 social media icons need to be on the bottom edge of the background image but I can't get them inline. I have tried several things (display:block-inline, float:left/right assignment, etc.) but all they do is move around and around.

What am I overlooking?

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="left">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>
            <b>Telephone:</b> 012345678<br/>
            <b>E-mail:</b> abc@abc.com
        <p>
        <div class="social">
            <a href="http://facebook.com" title="" id="facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a href="http://twitter.com" title="" id="twitter">Twitter</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body { font:14px Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; color:#282828; text-align:left; }
.footer { background:url('http://i.imgur.com/AhHgSJr.jpg') no-repeat; padding:5px; width:984px; height:268px; }
.footer .left { display:block; width:252px; float:left; padding:98px 0 0 40px; }
.footer .right { display:block;  width:252px; float:right; padding:98px 40px 0 0; }
.footer h3 { color:#a0cf67; font-size:21px; font-weight:bold; }
.footer p { padding:0 0 26px 0; }
.footer .social #facebook { background:url('http://i.imgur.com/g20ltEP.png') no-repeat; float:left; display:block; width:59; height:55px; overflow:hidden; text-indent:100%; white-space:nowrap; }
.footer .social #twitter { background:url(http://i.imgur.com/xteWM7e.png) no-repeat; display:block; width:58px; height:45px; overflow:hidden; text-indent:100%; white-space:nowrap; }
.footer-container .bottom-container { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the `display:block` and `float:left`.  View [here](http://jsfiddle.net/halifaxious/CeMCp/). The fiddle seems to work, but since it's not showing the icons (a jsFiddle issue), ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you seem to be missing/misunderstanding/overthinking:

1. The display setting is `inline-block`, *not* `block-inline`. If you want to control the height/width of these links, make sure your `display` setting is correct.
2. `<a>` tags are `display: inline` by default, meaning, if they have enough room, they will sit next to each other. If you just need to change the spacing between the two items, this is sufficient and no `display` property is needed at all.
3. Your Facebook link has no ID in your Fiddle. Make sure your actual markup has it. This could explain why `display: block; float: left;` doesn't work for you.
4. You're going overboard with your `.footer .social #twitter`/`.footer .social #facebook` lines in CSS. IDs are about as specific as CSS gets, and occur only once per page in valid HTML. Therefore, you only need `#twitter`/`#facebook` in your CSS (this likely won't fix your issue here, but may save you from headaches in other projects, and a good habit to get into).